# Cant create new category in Joomla 3.1.5

Tags: joomla, addition, categories

Every things is Ok menu,articles,but when creating new category it shows nothing in localhost

Comment: have you edited any of the core Joomla files?

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific. What steps did you take? Is the category published? What did you expect to happen and how is the outcome different from those expectations? Did you do any customization to your setup?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions and answers,I am absolutely sure that there is no any mistakes in installation,because i have made all process by video tutorial,in video category added to localhost without any problems,totally confused with that,let me show picture of what i have now and what i expect here is the link http://www.files.kg/file/8jM/Screen_Capture_%23309.png

Comment: Why do you expect your categories to appear in the breadcrumbs position? It's one thing to be sure everything is correct, it's a completely different thing to actually be, especially if you are inexperienced. Please explain *exactly* what you did so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All text/structure joomla content going to database, nothing is stored on localhost, only media. Your category is created in database.